# ROS time. Trying to recover time when recorded to a file

Tags: timestamp, ros, rosbag

I am trying to get the timestamp for a particular ROS message, record it in a file, read the file and recover the original timestamp. So far unsuccessfully .

Here is my code

```
import os
import os.path
import rosbag
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image

import rospy

IMG_DIRNAME = '/the/root/to/bags/'

#we get only one published topic time and quit
def main():
    rosbag_file = 'thebag.bag'
    rosbag_file= os.path.join(IMG_DIRNAME,rosbag_file)
    for topic, msg, t in  rosbag.Bag(rosbag_file).read_messages():
        if topic == '/the/topic/image':
            print(".")
            return t


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        time_stamp= main()    #I got the time stamp
        print("original ",time_stamp)
        print(time_stamp)
        print(time_stamp.secs)
        print(time_stamp.nsecs)
        print("recorded ",time_stamp.to_sec())
        print(time_stamp.to_sec())
        print("just to show ",time_stamp.to_nsec())

        ts=time_stamp.to_sec()

        #Here we record it in a file
        with open("afile.txt",'w') as f:
            f.write('{0}\n'.format(ts))
        
        with open("afile.txt",'r') as f:
            new_ts=float(f.read())
        

        time_new= rospy.Time.from_sec(new_ts)
        print("recovered ", time_new)
        print(time_new)
        print(time_new.secs)
        print(time_new.nsecs)

        print("==================================")
        print("other record",time_stamp.to_nsec())
        print(time_stamp.to_nsec())
        tns=time_stamp.to_nsec()
        #Here we record it in a file
        with open("afile2.txt",'w') as f:
            f.write('{0}\n'.format(tns))
        
        with open("afile2.txt",'r') as f:
            ff=f.read().strip("\n")
            print("read as")
            print(ff)
            new_tns=float(ff)

        print(new_tns)
        time_new_ns= rospy.Time(new_tns)
        print("recovered",time_new_ns)
        print(time_new_ns)
        print(time_new_ns.secs)  
        print(time_new_ns.nsecs)
```

As a result I got

```
.
('original ', rospy.Time[1625151029987577614])
1625151029987577614
1625151029
987577614
('recorded ', 1625151029.9875777)
1625151029.99
('just to show ', 1625151029987577614)
('recovered ', rospy.Time[1625151029990000009])
1625151029990000009
1625151029
990000009
==================================
('other record', 1625151029987577614)
1625151029987577614
read as
1625151029987577614
1.62515102999e+18
('recovered', rospy.Time[1625151029987577600000000000])
1625151029987577600000000000
1625151029987577600
0
```

So you can see that first I got the timestamp (original) and recorded the conversion to seconds (1625151029.99). I recorded it to a file (which has that number recorded) and the recovered timestamp is not the same as the original (the ns part went from 987577614 to 990000009).  I guess this was due to putting the `to_sec` conversion

In order to correct that I do the second part (after the ===).  I record the number of nsecs (1625151029987577614) which I read, first as a string correctly, then as a float (shown in scientific notation)
But in the last part ("recovered") I don't know how to convert this number correctly to ROS time. The value I got is totally wrong

How can I get the original timestamp here?

EDIT:
I tried

```
print("recalculated")
tt=rospy.Time( int(new_tns //1000000000), int(new_tns%1000000000))
print("recovered",tt)
print(tt)
print(tt.secs)  
print(tt.nsecs)
```

but although it got closer to the original , it still does not get it

```
recalculated
('recovered', rospy.Time[1625151029987577600])
1625151029987577600
1625151029
987577600
```

plust, couldn't be a simpler and proper way?

Answer (score 0):

The problem your having is actually coming from using `time_new.nsecs` incorrectly. Your expectation is that `nsecs` will show the *total* time since epoch in nano seconds. However, this field actually shows *nano seconds since seconds (since epoch)*. So, you're just extracting the nano seconds after what is shown by `time_new.secs`. If you want to do a full conversation always use `to_secs()` and `to_nsecs()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formulae to covert the `time_stamp.secs` and `time_stamp.nsecs` to `time_stamp_since_epoch`

```
time_stamp_since_epoch = time_stamp.secs + time_stamp.nsecs*1e-9
```